# Should the [seed-starting] and [germination] tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed today that we have tags for both [seed-starting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seed-starting) and [germination](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germination) (with the latter having a synonym, [germinating](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germinating)). Both tags have wikis, but the one for [germination](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germination) has a lot more detail. The wiki for [seed-starting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seed-starting) even mentions "germination" in the excerpt.

Is there a difference between starting seeds and germination? Should we mark one as being a synonym of the other, and if so, which one should be the master (i.e. the one that appears on all future questions using the tag).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically you can germinate fungal spores and bacteria as well as seeds from plants. If you only go by the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germination) then germination includes everything seed starting implies and a little more.

The only thing seed starting has going for it is that it is more recognizable to the user base as I believe there are less users who use germination as their first choice of key word.

I think it would be reasonable to make seed starting as a synonym for germination.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've created the synonym.