# This post refuses the [seed-starting] tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, editing

This post:

- [Why is it best to start seeds in shallow trays?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17615/why-is-it-best-to-start-seeds-in-shallow-trays)

had a pending [edit proposal](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/6806). The user who proposed the edit was unable to add the tag [seed-starting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seed-starting), so I clicked the 'improve' button, added the tag, and approved the edit.

The tag disappeared. So I clicked 'edit tags', put it back in, and it disappeared again.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [seed-starting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seed-starting) tag is a synonym for [germination](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germination) (along with [germinating](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germinating)), so if you try to use it, the system will remap it to [germination](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germination) automatically.

If you click through the [seed-starting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seed-starting) link, you'll see that it shows "germination" at the top right (perhaps not the most obvious place to put it, admittedly). The list of synonyms is also available from a link on that page.

See [Should the [seed-starting] and [germination] tags be synonyms?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/490/26) for more information.